# What is a concise synonym for "height above the ground"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am writing a paper and need to mention the height that a person lifted their foot above the ground multiple times. I feel like writing "height above the ground" every time is a bit "wasteful" and am looking for a more concise alternative.

A sample sentence:

> The participants foot ___ was 10 cm higher than in the control group.

Right now I abbreviate to just "height", but I feel like this loses a bit of clarity ... especially if I talk about "foot height" which sounds more like the "size of the foot" to me.

Others use "elevation", but to my supervisor this sounds more like "elevation of land".

Are there any other alternatives (that I, as a non-native speaker am not aware of)?

Comment: "(foot) height" or "(foot) elevation" seem ok, and the meaning should be clear from the context (you could prefix with "maximum" or "peak" if that makes it clearer). "foot lift" might be an alternative, but I prefer the first two.

Comment: You could use '*position*' and start by explaining that position means "height above the ground".

Comment: Do you need *any* word to fill the gap? *The participant's foot was 10 cm higher than in the control group.* (added apostrophe) Perhaps use a word in a different place: *The participant's foot was **raised** 10 cm higher than in the control group.*

Comment: Comment answer not worthy of full answer: don't bother with the blank. The way you say it in idiomatic English is: "The participants foot was 10 cm higher than in the control group." That's how you use 'higher'. That's what 'higher' means.

Comment: @Mitch Is there ellipsis involved by any chance? Does a fuller version of the sentence read _"The participant's foot was 10 cm higher than [it was] in the control group."_ _than in the control group_ sounds kinda odd, doesn't it?

Comment: @user405662 Is "it was"  removed or is it just how you say it? I don't know what the difference is. Maybe just: "The participants foot was 10 cm higher than the control group."

Comment: “The participant raised his/her foot 10 cm. higher . . .” or elevated instead of raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Height* would be the best choice from an aviation context. In that domain, *altitude* refers to your distance above sea level, while *elevation* refers to the terrain's distance above sea level. *Height* refers to exactly what you want, which is the distance from you to the ground. This should be sufficiently clear so long as you're not also trying to describe height/thickness of the foot itself in the same text.